# Husband and wife applying at the same company

Tags: hiring-process, united-states

I've had trouble researching this: my spouse and I enjoy working at the same place and it just so happens that it's time for us to find another job. We work in different fields, in different departments. Is there a process for us applying at another company - for two different positions - if we get accepted? Do we have to disclose our relationship?

Edit: we're in the states, and there's not a particular company in mind - we'll be applying at a few.

Basically, the question is, must we tell them if we get offers? Or should it be earlier, during the interview?

Comment: Some companies have specific policies against married people working together even in different departments. At one of those companies, if you do not disclose, you would be fired when they found out.

Comment: Do you HAVE to work at the same company?

Comment: It'd be nice, of course it's not really required.

Comment: It should be mentioned that your "same company" policy is not without risk. What happens when that company goes through a round of layoffs or decides it can't afford to dole out bonuses this year? Being in the same company means that your entire family is affected by negative events. IMO its better to diversify family employment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you both get short listed then tell them.  If you tell them earlier they may just eliminate you from consideration.

If you wait for the offer they could feel like you were not respectful of their time.